# git push error: not Signed-off-by author/committer/uploader in commit message footer

Tags: git, git-push, git-cherry-pick

I am working on an issue on my local repository, and I found that this bug was fixed in the kernel.org repository.

So now I am trying to pull this fix from the kernel.org branch and `cherry-pick` it to my local gerrit. And I am trying to maintain the commit message of the commit from the kernel.org branch.

When I try to push this fix on my local gerrit, I face the following error:

```
To ssh://<username>@123.321.12.1:1234/mirror-sec/asdfgt/hjks
 ! [remote rejected] <branch> -> refs/for/<branch> (not Signed-off-by author/committer/uploader in commit message footer)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<username>@123.321.12.1:1234/mirror-sec/asdfgt/hjks'
```

Following are the steps that I followed:

1. Runned `git remote add 'tag' git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux`
2. Runned `git fetch 'tag'`
3. Searched for the commit in `git log 'tag'/master`
4. cherry-picked the specific commit-id needed: `git cherry-pick <commit-id>`
5. Runned `git commit --amend`, to get a new change-id for the cherry-picked commit-id
6. Funned `git push` to submit the change to the local gerrit: `git push ssh://<username>@123.321.12.1:1234/mirror-sec/asdfgt/hjks <branch>:refs/for/<branch>`

When I followed the above steps, I face the error mentioned above.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Any information that I am overlooking would help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For other people scraping head the answer you can try this:

```
git commit --amend -s
```

Answer (score 1):

Projects in Gerrit can be configured to require a Signed-off-by in the footer of the commit message to enforce that every change is signed by the author, committer or uploader. If for a project a Signed-off-by is required and the commit message footer does not contain it, Gerrit rejects to push the commit with this error message.

This policy can be bypassed by having the access right Forge Committer.

This error may happen for different reasons

if you do not have the access right to forge the committer identity:

missing Signed-off-by in the commit message footer
Signed-off-by is contained in the commit message footer but it’s neither from the author, committer nor uploader

Signed-off-by from the author, committer or uploader is contained in the commit message but not in the footer (last paragraph)

To be able to push your commits you can amend your commit and add the signed off line or use forge committer option in your local gerrit